# Why some HTML elements aren't styleable?

Tags: html, css

Why some HTML elements like: radio buttons, check boxes, datalists... aren't styleable? I mean ... this is so bad that we have to create a custom element over the standard element so we can style it 
 Is there any specific reason to that?

I'm not asking for workarounds for these elements, I'm asking WHY they can't be styled natively ... Is there something in the HTML specification that prevents these elements to be styled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms) has an explanation:

> In the early days of the Web—around 1995—form controls were added to HTML in [the HTML 2 specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt). Due to the complexity of form widgets, implementors chose to rely on the underlying operating system to manage and render them...... Because users are accustomed to the visual appearance of their respective platforms, browser vendors are reluctant to make form controls stylable"